# Simple Test can not open HTTPS URL

Tags: php, sockets, url, simpletest

I'm running UI test using the Simple Test. Below is the code.

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once('simpletest/web_tester.php');

class TestOfRankings extends WebTestCase {
    function testWeAreTopOfGoogle() {
       $this->get('https://ua-useast1a01-01-internalip.qa.host.net/ultraadmin/');
       }
    }
?>
```

I'm getting below error:

> E_WARNING: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /home/okhatav/PHP/simpletest/socket.php on line 255 Exception 1!
>   Unexpected PHP error [fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given] severity [2] in
>   [/home/okhatav/PHP/simpletest/socket.php line 255]
>           in testWeAreTopOfGoogle
>           in TestOfRankings 1) Error reading socket [Cannot open [ua-useast1a01-01-internalip.qa.host.net:443] with [] within [15]
>   seconds]
>           in testWeAreTopOfGoogle
>           in TestOfRankings FAILURES!!!

Comment: When you put that url in a browser window it says server not found.

Comment: use the try catch block, the server does not exist

Comment: This URL is valid url and works too.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded simpletest and run the exact same code and received a similar but slightly more informative message:

> Exception: TestOfRankings -> testWeAreTopOfGoogle -> Unexpected PHP error [fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given] severity [2] in [/var/www/html/simpletest/socket.php line 255]
>
> Fail: TestOfRankings -> testWeAreTopOfGoogle -> Error reading socket [Cannot open [ua-useast1a01-01-internalip.qa.host.net:443] with [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known] within [15] seconds]

This indicates the URL specified is not valid or is having trouble resolving. Trying to access the URL directly results in the following:

[image]

Changing it to a valid URL works without error.

While it may not be related, if you compare the [network map](http://www.host.net/networkmaps/) of the host in question to that of the recent [Dyn attacks](http://www.theverge.com/2016/10/24/13380448/ddos-dyn-attack-internet-infrastructure) it lines up almost perfectly. You could try contacting the host to see if they're aware of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of simpletest (you're not running the latest - the error lines don't match up with the current code). You can get from https://github.com/simpletest/simpletest or just run `composer update` if you installed that way.

In particular, this commit: https://github.com/simpletest/simpletest/commit/91b0d224a1c81aacbf888b68f9812f5ab2610114 appears to be the one that should tell you the URL is invalid.